# PHP - Find set of keywords in an articles

Tags: php

The concept is that I have an array of keywords, and a articles. I am wondering what would be the best way to find out if any of those keywords are present in the set of articles, bearing in mind performance and speed.

Basically, the keywords consists of 3 or more words but not exceeded in 10 words. It will look if the keywords exist in the articles then it will return only the keywords that found in the article.

Assuming that we have an article:

```
$articles = "Maybe it’s less true than it used to be that people are made of 
       place--that the same elements that form coal and clay and bogs and ice form 
       faces, voices and characters. I wrote my first collection of short stories, 
       The Bostons, in homage to this book, hoping, as did Joyce’s young Stephen 
       Dedalus, to encounter for the millionth time the reality of experience and to 
       forge in the smithy of my soul the uncreated conscience of some island-dwellers
       I knew."
```

Keywords:

```
$keywords = "less true than, people are made, smithy of my soul, uncreated 
             conscience, this is a test string"
```

out put mus be:

```
"less true than, people are made, smithy of my soul, uncreated conscience"
```

I already program it by using

```
  $articles = mb_split( ' +', $articles );
  foreach ( $articles as $key => $word )
 $articles [$key] = trim($word);

  //Search for keywords     
  $keywords = str_replace(' ', '', $keywords);
  $keywords =  mb_split( '[ ,]+', mb_strtolower( $keywords, 'utf-8' ) );

  $result = implode(',', array_intersect($keywords, $articles );
```

but it only works per one keyword. I don't know how to do it by multiple keywords.

Comment: So your keywords can actually consist of multiple words? For example one "keyword" in your example is "less true than", right?

Comment: You've heard of regular expression and preg_match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strpos()` is what you need. This works -

```
$res = Array();
foreach(explode(", ",$keywords) as $keyword){
    if(strpos($articles, $keyword)){
        $res[] = $keyword;
    }
}
$matched = implode($res,", ");
var_dump($matched);
/** OUTPUT **/
string 'less true than, people are made, smithy of my soul, uncreated conscience' (length=72)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) could help you.
This works, as you can see [here](http://3v4l.org/fnuih).
Your problem might have been the break in the keywords string?

```
$articles = "Maybe it’s less true than it used to be that people are made of 
   place--that the same elements that form coal and clay and bogs and ice form 
   faces, voices and characters. I wrote my first collection of short stories, 
   The Bostons, in homage to this book, hoping, as did Joyce’s young Stephen 
   Dedalus, to encounter for the millionth time the reality of experience and to 
   forge in the smithy of my soul the uncreated conscience of some island-dwellers
   I knew.";

$keywords = "less true than, people are made, smithy of my soul, uncreated conscience, this is a test string";

$keywordsArray = explode(', ',$keywords);

$pattern = '/'.implode('|',$keywordsArray).'/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$articles,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array_unique(
    preg_match_all(
        '/'.implode('|', explode(', ', $keywords).'/',
        $articles
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

$articles = "Maybe it’s less true than it used to be that people are made of 
   place--that the same elements that form coal and clay and bogs and ice form 
   faces, voices and characters. I wrote my first collection of short stories, 
   The Bostons, in homage to this book, hoping, as did Joyce’s young Stephen 
   Dedalus, to encounter for the millionth time the reality of experience and to 
   forge in the smithy of my soul the uncreated conscience of some island-dwellers
   I knew." ;

$keywords = "less true than, people are made, smithy of my soul, uncreated conscience, this is a test string";

$keyword = explode(',',$keywords);

foreach($keyword AS $key=>$value) {

```
if(strpos($articles,$value)) {

      $finalstring  .= $value.',';
 }   
}
```

echo $finalstring;